# String replacement in JSON using regular expression to ignore object keys

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this JSON:

```json
{
  "agent": "Teste",
  "obs": "obs 2 in other obs",
  "id": 4,
  "queue": "Suply",
  "name": "Other"
}
```

I need a regular expression to produce this JSON:

```json
{
  "agent": "Teste",
  "obs": "<b>obs</b> 2 in other <b>obs</b>",
  "id": 4,
  "queue": "Suply",
  "name": "Other"
}
```

I fail in replace because the key `"obs":` is replaced too.

Comment: Parse it into a JS object, mutate it with JS, and then convert it back

Comment: Thanks friend, I just put an example. My json is huge and I need to mark only the values found by a search without marking the keys in case the user enters one. I want to do a search on a pretty big json with lots of keys, arrays and objects and mark where the values were found.

Comment: "My json is huge" then why are you processing it on the client? "I need this with Regex" why? Objects are much easier to work with and if you think deserialization is slow...

Comment: @morganney The question might be clear but sometimes the aimed solution makes so little sense that additional context is needed. (I.e. an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).) Regexes and JSON's don't mix well. OP mentions that they want to "_do a search on a pretty big json with lots of keys, arrays and objects_". If any key in that JSON contains "obs" without ending in it (e.g. `"obstacles": true`), it will break the JSON with your answer.

Comment: @Ivar that's a simple fix with updated regex, so it seems the original question is clear. Feel free to ask an updated question to address your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```js
/obs(?!":)/g
```

It uses the [negative lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#basic_negative_lookahead_assertion).

```js
const json = JSON.stringify({"agent": "Teste","obs": "obs 2 in other obs","id": 4,"queue": "Suply","name":"Other"})

console.log(json.replace(/(obs)(?!":)/g, '<b>$1</b>'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a regex with 2 capture groups. The first capture group is replaced with <b> and </b> around it. Then the second capture group is replaced. Because the second capture group excludes the colon, the keys are not altered. There are two period characters as one of them is to take into account the forward slash introduced by JSONStringify() and the other is for the quote mark after a key.

```js
const JSONString = JSON.stringify('{"agent": "Teste","obs": "obs 2 in other obs","id": 4,"queue": "Suply","name":"Other"}');

const re = /(obs)(..[^:])/g;

let newJSONString = JSONString.replace(re, '<b>$1</b>$2');

newObject = JSON.parse(newJSONString);

console.log(newObject);
```